# Alterar texto de TextView

Tags: java, android

Suponhamos que tenho um texto dentro de uma TextView, existe a possibilidade de alterar android:text remotamente, sem mexer no xml, por meio de uma postagem em um banco de dados externo, por exemplo, uma frase jogada em em um banco que pode ser alterada a qualquer minuto, é possível faze-la aparecer no campo android:text sendo alterada a cada postagem?

(estou estudando um modo, mas me surgiu essa duvida se consigo fazer deste jeito)

Comment: Para alterar o texto do `TextView` recomendo dar uma olhada na documentação do método `setText` ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence,android.widget.TextView.BufferType). Como uma recomendação sugiro o curso de Android da Udacity (https://www.udacity.com/courses#!/android). Boa sorte nos estudos.

Comment: Eu tenho pego o curso do Udacity, mas vou ler o artigo sobre o método setText. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Resumo:

depois de uns estudos, notei mais viável para realização utilizar a webview no xml do que alterar de uma textview.